# Load stylesheet with javascript and localStorage

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using a Jekyll website, doesn't really matter because this is a static page, I just write it as additional info.

**Desired behavior:**

I want to load my stylesheet via javascript, so it can depend of a local stored value, let's say `dark` and `light`.

I have done a little test of loading it by JS with the following code (which works).

GREEN

```
<head>
  ...
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/{{'light'}}.css">
  ...
</head>
```

This loads the CSS file called "light" as expected.

But now I want to depend of the `localStorage`, with a variable `theme` that has `light` as value. I tried the following:

RED

```
<head>
  ...
  <script>
    var storedTheme = window.localStorage.getItem('theme'); //Tested and working in console
    theme = storedTheme ? storedTheme : 'light'; //global variable (also readable in console)
  </script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/{{theme}}.css"> <!-- cant read global variable -->
  ...
</head>
```

Using global variables doesn't work, it gives me a 404 error as the stylesheet path is `/assets/css/.css`.

After that I thought that maybe creating an element would do the trick and I created one manually to test it:

RED

```
<head>
...
<p id="theme" style="display:none;">dark</p>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/{{document.getElementById('theme').innerHTML}}.css">
...
</head>
```

And nope, the path still appears as: `/assets/css/.css`

Comment: You've to build the link tag with JS, and append it to the head section.

Comment: The double curly braces is server-side template syntax, you cannot use it like that. However you can simply do `document.querySelector('link[rel="stylesheet"]').href = "...";` from your code (add an `id` to the <link> if there's more than one)

Comment: @Teemu It works but there is another problem, the HTML renders without CSS for like 0.3s before the stylesheet is loaded.

Comment: You can do what Chris has suggested too. Notice, that the script has to be placed after the link tag, otherwise the link doesn't exist at the time you're trying to refer it. You can also disable a stylesheet. Load both as disabled, and enable the one, which of id you get from the local storage.

Comment: Yeah I did it too, I was about to tag you both but I new here and looks like I can't do that. It happens the same error, even placing the script the line after the ```link```. @Teemu

Comment: @ChrisG as commented above, the HTML renders with no CSS for less than 1s but enough to see it.

Comment: Yes, you can ping only a single user per comment. It takes some time to load the external CSS, no matter how it is done. [Disabling stylesheets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StyleSheet/disabled) might be what you need. What ever way you're solving this, the scripts and the links must be placed in the head section, otherwise you will get the CSSless moment when loading the page.

Comment: You could add `style="display: none"` to your <body> and show it after setting the stylesheet href. The alternative is to store the setting in the user's server-side profile.

Comment: To avoid the Flick Of Unstyled Content, you can start with overriding the existing stylesheet and only remove it after a second. Something like this: `var link1 = document.querySelector('link[rel="stylesheet"]'), link2 = document.createElement('link'); link2.rel = 'stylesheet'; link2.href = '(WHATEVER)'; link1.after(link2); window.setTimeout( () => link1.remove(), 1000);`

Comment: I did what @ChrisG said, making body ```display: none;``` and under the ```body``` call an async JS function that checks every 50ms if the stylesheet is loaded or not with: ```document.styleSheets.length``` . I will wait a couple of hours before marking this as resolved in case that someone has a better idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change styles on the `<body>` you get FOUC (**F**lash **O**f **U**nstyled **C**ontent). Try using a close equivalent like `<main>`  and spread it 100% x 100% and `<html>` and `<body>` as well, but give them `margin` and `padding` of 0 in order to ensure `<main>` covers them completely.

The `[disabled]` attribute for the `<link>` is the best way of toggling them because they are still loaded but inert. Also, in the example there is a function called `loadTheme(e)` that is loaded on the `'DOMContentLoaded'` event which insures that all of the DOM is loaded before hand. The example below will not work because `localStorage` is blocked on SO. There is a functioning example on [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/rxZonjfs2Ttfr32H?open=lib%2Fscript.js). To test it:

1. Click the green <kbd>Preview</kbd> button.
2. Another frame should appear on the right. Within the frame is the webpage example click the <kbd>☀️</kbd> button.
3. It should be in dark mode now. Next, click the refresh <kbd>⟳</kbd> button located in the mini-toolbar within the frame or press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> for Windows OS or <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>return</kbd> for Mac OS.
4. The page should still be in dark mode.

```css
/* night.css 
main {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
*/

/* default.css */
:root {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font: 1ch/1.5 'Segoe UI';
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 4ch;
}

main {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}

form {
  width: 80vw;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

fieldset {
  width: max-content;
  min-height: 25px;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding: 0 1.5px 1.5px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background: inherit;
  color: inherit;
}

button {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 4rem;
  text-align: center;
  background: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#theme::before {
  content: '☀️';
}

.night #theme::before {
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href='lib/default.css' rel='stylesheet'>
  <link class='night' href='lib/night.css' rel='stylesheet' disabled>
  <style></style>
</head>

<body>
  <main>
    <form id='UI'>
      <fieldset name='box'>
        <legend>Theme</legend>
        <button id='theme' type='button'></button>
      </fieldset>
      <p>Click the "Theme" switch to toggle between `disabled` `true` and `false` on `night.css` and `light.css` `
        <link>`s.</p>
    </form>
  </main>
  <script>
    const UI = document.forms.UI;
    const M = document.querySelector('main');
    const L = document.querySelector('.night')

    const switchTheme = e => {
      const clk = e.target;
      if (clk.matches('button')) {
        M.classList.toggle('night');
        L.toggleAttribute('disabled');
      }
      let status = M.className === 'night' ? 'on' : 'off';
      localStorage.setItem('theme', status);
    };

    const loadTheme = e => {
      let cfg = localStorage.getItem('theme');
      if (cfg === 'on') {
        M.classList.add('night');
        L.removeAttribute('disabled');
      } else {
        M.classList.remove('night');
        L.setAttribute('disabled', true);
      }
    };

    UI.addEventListener('click', switchTheme);
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', loadTheme);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```