# Dark/Light mode keep between switching through navigation

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

so I'm having an issue with this code not keeping the color of when the person chooses to switch to lightmode then move to a different page it resets. How would I change it so it could stay the color they chose between pages.

Here is the HTML

```
                 <div class="switch-wrap">
                    <div id="switch" class="hover-target">
                        <div id="circle"></div>
                    </div>
                    <!--Credits to Ivan Grozdic Navigation/Dark/Light-->
                    <p><span>dark</span> - <span>light</span></p>
                </div>
```

Here is the javascript/jquery

```
    $("#switch").on('click', function () {
        if ($("body").hasClass("light")) {
            $("body").removeClass("light");
            $("#switch").removeClass("switched");
        }
        else {
            $("body").addClass("light");
            $("#switch").addClass("switched");
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

I have tried doing a document.cookies(ifDarkmode.istrue) and keeping it but I haven not gotten it to work since I am new to coding.

Comment: Try using `localStorage` to store info, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71032440/2813224)

Comment: If you want it to store the color between pages **only when browser open** but OK to forget it once it closed then use **sessionStorage**. It works like **localStorage** but for one session only. :)