# Dark mode flash of white background

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, darkmode

I'm working on dark mode for an ASP.NET app using HTML, CSS and JS. Everything works great except for this FOIT issue, "flash of incorrect theme." Upon loading any page on the site, there's about a millisecond (though sometimes longer) flash of white. I'm aware of why this happens (the JS is executing after the CSS) but not sure what to do.

I've tried putting a script in the `<head>` to block the page from rendering, and then having another script in the `<body>` that shows the `<body>` only after the dark theme has been applied; this did not work and I'm not sure why.

I've scoured the internet but nothing I've tried makes any difference. Would greatly appreciate any help, thanks so much.

(Sorry if I'm leaving crucial info out, I'm quite the noob with this stuff)

JS:

```
<script>
                window.addEventListener("load", function () {
                    const btn = document.querySelector(".btn-toggle");
                    const theme = localStorage.getItem("theme");
                    if (theme) document.body.classList.toggle("dark-theme", theme === "dark")
                    btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
                        const dark = document.body.classList.contains("dark-theme")
                        document.body.classList.toggle("dark-theme");
                        localStorage.setItem("theme", dark ? "light" : "dark");

                    });
                });       
        </script>
```

HTML:

```
<li class="theme-btn">
<button class="btn-toggle dark-theme" id="btn-toggle">Change Theme</button>
</li>
```

CSS:

```
body.dark-theme {
            font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            font-size: 14px;
            line-height: 1.42857143;
            background-color: #121212;
        }

.dark-theme .well
{
    background-color: #181818;
    color: #c1c1c1;
    border: none;
}

.dark-theme .btn-default {
    background-color: #222222;
    color: #c1c1c1;
    border: solid thin #353535;
}
```

Comment: You should be using document loaded and not window load. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71032440/2813224