# I'm trying to teach myself the classList.toggle function & I can't make it pass a class to an element

Tags: javascript, html, css, addeventlistener

I got Bing AI to write me a basic toggle button, that should switch between light mode & dark mode. I parsed it into, I suppose, 4 files. An HTML file, an SASS file that compiles to CSS, and a Javascript file. However, the button doesn't click or run.

I would ideally like to put a `console.log()` in there to test what's happening with the button, but truthfully, I don't know how or where to write that. Since I asked Bing, it used concepts that I haven't learned yet, & it says the code works perfectly, but it doesn't on any of my browsers. It works when I add the class "dark-mode" manually to the body and html tag, but the whole point of learning `addEventListener` & `classlist.toggle()`, is that I can use a button to toggle a class into and out of a particular element.

Basically, I want to learn to create a super basic dark mode, for a super basic HTML page.

```css
body {
  background-color: rgba(255, 247, 174, 0.87);
  color: black;
}

body.dark-mode {
  background-color: rgb(62, 74, 236);
  color: white;
}

#darkToggle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: #2ab1ce;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#darkToggle.dark-mode {
  background-color: #ea4b3c;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../src/style/css/dom.css">
  <script src="../../src/script/dom.js" defer />
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Dark Mode Toggle Button</h1>
  <button id="darkToggle">Dark mode</button>
</body>
</html>
```

```
// get the button element by id
let button = document.getElementById("darkToggle");

// add a click event listener to the button
button.addEventListener("click", function () {
  // toggle the dark-mode class on the body and button elements
  document.body.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
  button.classList.toggle("dark-mode");

  // check if the body element has the dark-mode class
  if (document.body.classList.contains("dark-mode")) {
    // change the button text to light mode
    button.textContent = "Light mode";
  } else {
    // change the button text to dark mode
    button.textContent = "Dark mode";
  }
});
```

Here is a link to [Codepen](https://codepen.io/fo9yh/pen/xxQZdJq)

It works on Codepen.io but not in Firefox or Edge locally. I swear all my links are correct. Edit: I am now uncertain whether my links are correct.

Comment: what is your question? What error do you get locally? The codepen works for me on firefox. Check your browser console (F12) most probably you got some file protocoll issues because i assume you do not run a local webserver

Comment: I tries Codepan code is perfactly working. May be there is some mistakes in some spelling or If you created external css and javascript file then there can be error in importing it. Check it or share it code of that. Hope it will help  you...Thank you...!

Comment: A good start would be to share your JS code here within the snippet not on external resources

Comment: I added my javascript. I think I did it correctly.

Comment: Any errors in console? PS Add the `defer` attribute to your `<script defer` (as you did) or rather place all your script tags right before the closing `</body>` tag. The reason being - the DOM is not yet read, but you're trying to attach event listeners to Elements that are not yet discovered.

Comment: Also, you don't have to toggle with JS the `.dark-mode` class on the button specifically. Just use CSS like: `.dark-mode #darkToggle {`

Comment: Also, your script is not persisting by any means that theme after page refresh - so stop what you're doing and head to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63033934/383904 to see how `localStorage` can help

Comment: See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71032440/2813224) for a better example.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan If you're willing, could you please elaborate on that bit about using CSS instead of JS?

Comment: You only need to toggle the class using JS on one element only. i.e: `"body"`.  Then all it takes is to use CSS like: `body.dark-mode #someButton {` or shorter `.dark-mode #myButton {` that way all you need is one line of JS, not several.

Answer (score 0):

Did you link your`.js` file to `.html` file? on CodePen it's linked automatically

```html
<script src="./your-js-file.js" defer />
```

Comment: Mine is linked like this: `<script src="../../src/script/dom.js"></script>`

Comment: I edited it into `<script src="../../src/script/dom.js" defer />`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because your Script is loaded before the HTML. Move your script to bottom, just before the closing body tag `</body>`, or try to add `async` in the script to make it download asynchronously.

Try below code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<style>
body {
  background-color: rgba(255, 247, 174, 0.87);
  color: black;
}

body.dark-mode {
  background-color: rgb(62, 74, 236);
  color: white;
}

#darkToggle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: #2ab1ce;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#darkToggle.dark-mode {
  background-color: #ea4b3c;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
 <h1>Dark Mode Toggle Button</h1>
  <button id="darkToggle">Dark mode</button>

</body>

<script>

    let button = document.getElementById("darkToggle");
    
    
    button.addEventListener
    // add a click event listener to the button
    button.addEventListener("click", function () {
        console.log(" ************* ");
      // toggle the dark-mode class on the body and button elements
      document.body.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
      button.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
    
      // check if the body element has the dark-mode class
      if (document.body.classList.contains("dark-mode")) {
        // change the button text to light mode
        button.textContent = "Light mode";
      } else {
        // change the button text to dark mode
        button.textContent = "Dark mode";
      }
    });
    
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: You're very close to what my error was. I initially solved it by moving my script tag underneath my html altogether. Then I queried Bing about it & it mentioned that defer in the script tag also holds the js from running before the html is parsed.

My issue was in how I was linking my js in my script tag. My solution was this:

`<script src="../../src/script/dom.js" defer></script>`

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I initially solved it by moving my script tag underneath my html altogether. Then I queried Bing about it & it mentioned that defer in the script tag also holds the js from running before the html is parsed. My issue was in how I was linking my js in my script tag. My solution was this:

`<script src="../../src/script/dom.js" defer></script>`

Thanks everyone.